# Ruby initialize: why doesn't it execute my read instruction

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dsl

This is code from the day 3 of the Ruby section of 7 programming languages in 7 weeks. I can't get it to output anything if I don't write m.read just after m = RubyCsv.new

Shouldn't the initialize method take care of that ?

To test you can use a simple rubycsv.txt file containing

> one, two
>
> > 1, 2

And here is the ruby code:

```
module ActsAsCsv

def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
end

module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_csv
        include InstanceMethods
    end
end

module InstanceMethods
    def read
        @csv_contents = []
        filename = 'rubycsv.txt'
        file = File.new(filename)
        @headers = file.gets.chomp.split(', ')
        file.each do |row|
            @csv_contents << row.chomp.split(', ')
        end
    end

    attr_accessor :headers, :csv_contents

    def initalize
        read
    end
end
end

class RubyCsv
include ActsAsCsv
acts_as_csv 
end

m = RubyCsv.new
**m.read** #this shouldn't be necessary according to the book
puts m.headers.inspect
puts m.csv_contents.inspect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the initialize method take care of that ?

It should. Your method however is called "initalize".

Also: for CSV use existing CSV libraries, and try to use File.open instead of File.new (this shows the mode you are using for opening the file).